# Photocurrent in photodiode smaller than expected

Tags: photodiode, reverse-bias

I have a question regarding the usage of the phototransistor [SFH 203 P](https://docs.rs-online.com/160e/0900766b808b25c3.pdf), which I want to use for a project, where I need a small fall- and rise-time. The data sheet (I think) implies that if I use the photodiode as follows (in reverse bias) I should get a photocurrent of about 800µA (see page 3 under "Rise and fall time of the photocurrent").

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLnoe8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But unfortunately I only measure 2.3µA with bright room lighting. Did I misinterpret the [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/160e/0900766b808b25c3.pdf), use the wrong circuit or is my photodiode maybe broken?

Comment: 800uA is nearly 1mA. That's a butt load of current for a photodiode unless your photodiode is huge and/or you're shining a laser directly into it.

Comment: Are you re-inventing the opto-coupler?

Comment: Not really. I want to use the mentioned photodiode and an IR LED to measure the speed of light (over a distance of a few meters).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, that sounds about right. I don't know where you got the 800 µA figure from — both the table and the graph indicate much less.

"Bright office lighting" is about 500 lux. The sensitivity of the SFH 203 P is specified as minimum 5 µA, typical 9.5 µA @ 1000 lux.

The graph in the middle of page 4 agrees with this.

The rise and fall times were measured with a much brighter pulse of light than room lighting -- probably a laser or flashtube. Interestingly, none of the graphs go up that far, implying that that would not be a "normal" regime of operation.

Comment: I used the parameters on page 3 under "Rise and fall time of the photocurrent". There a current of 800µA is mentioned.

Comment: @David Tweed a photodiode is not a linear component. Doubling lux won't double current.

Comment: @HelenaWells: Actually, it pretty much is, at least over a reasonable range. That's the whole idea behind "quantum efficiency" -- a certain number of photons gives you a certain number of photoelectrons.

Comment: Not all photoelectron diffuse.

Comment: @HelenaWells: I'm not sure where you're going with this. Photoelectrons are created in the depletion region of the reverse-biased diode junction, and they are strongly driven out by the E-field that exists in that region. So you're right in a way -- they don't "diffuse".

Comment: I am talking about the photovoltaic mode.

Comment: @Helena Wells: Perhaps provide some data or an example?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: PV mode is completely off the topic of this question, and in particular, my answer. If you want to discuss it, take it to chat.

Answer (score 4):

> I should get a photocurrent of about 800µA (see page 3 under "Rise and fall time of the photocurrent").

From the datasheet:

Photosensitive area: 1 mm^2

Sensitivity: 0.86 A/W (at 850nm), about 0.5 in the visible.

To get 800uA in the visible, you would need 1.6mW.  From a 1x1 mm area, that is 1600 w per square meter, or about 2.5 times as bright as noon-time sunlight.  No way you're going to get that kind of current indoors without an arc lamp or a laser beam.

If you need more current, get an avalanche photodiode (about 100x more current) or a silicon photomultiplier (about 1,000,000x more current).  They're actually not that much more expensive than the diode you have, although bias voltage will be 30-40v.

Comment: *[V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt)* (not *v*)